# Classify each word in a paragraph (TF Keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

I want to create a model to turn vectors of `input_len` integers between 0 and `vocab_size` to vectors of `input_len` integers between 0 and 31.

The order of the integers matters, as these vectors represent paragraphs I am trying to classify each word of, with 32 possible categories.

I have the following training data:

The paragraphs themselves (inputs) formatted as arrays of words which have been numbered 0-`vocab_size`, and padded or cut off to `input_len` words
Labels (outputs) formatted as equally long arrays of labels 0-31 (0 being none)

A made-up example input might look like: `[12,4,63,2,9]`, and an output might look like `[0,0,3,0,7]`.

```py
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=input_len),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, input_shape=(input_len, embedding_dim),
                         return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')
])

model.compile('adam', 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

The code above throws the error

> InvalidArgumentError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 1000"

Currently, `input_len = 1000`.

TLDR, I have an input of shape `(training_set_size, input_len)` and want the LSTM to have an output of shape `(training_set_size, input_len)`.

Comment: Does it tell you which line is throwing the error? Or is it just when you try to compile/fit?

Comment: What's the shape of your `y_train`? If you are using `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`, it should *not* be one-hot encoded, so it needs to be a vector of size `(training_set_size, input_len)`, where the value for each word in your `input_len` is the integer associated with class that you want, 0-31.

Comment: The shape of y_train is (training_set_size, input_len), and it is NOT one hot encoded. Also, yes it is throwing the error only when I try to fit it. It compiles just fine.

Comment: Try wrapping your `Dense` layer in `keras.layers.TimeDistributed()` and let me know if that fixes it. Without your data, it's hard to test on my end. If it works, I'll put a little more information into an answer.

Comment: This did not work. However, I did not know that TimeDistributed() existed, and looking into it more led me to a tutorial I will now go through to see if that helps. Thanks!